# How to store days of week in database and display their names using Symfony/Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

What is the best way to store the names of days week in database and display them?

I've already figuered out to store it as integers from 0 to 4 (in my case I need only days from monday to friday) but maybe there is some better way to do that? It's good that I can easily sort them, but how can I display the names in twig template?

I guess I could do it with `{% if %}` tag but maybe there is some simpler way? Basically, it should be some kind of dictionary, but I don't really know what is the best practise for it.

Comment: I would add a Twig function to do the conversion for me, mostly so I can find where I used it later more easily.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out simpler than I thought.

```
// src/Twig/AppExtension.php

public function getFunctions(): array
{
    return [
        new TwigFunction('nameOfDay', [$this, 'nameOfDay']),
    ];
}

public function nameOfDay($num)
{
    if (0 === $num) {
        return 'Monday';
    } elseif (1 === $num) {
        return 'Tueasday';
    } elseif (2 === $num) {
        return 'Wednesday';
    } elseif (3 === $num) {
        return 'Thursday';
    } elseif (4 === $num) {
        return 'Friday';
    }
}
```